# golang - net/http/pprof doesn't work

Tags: go, pprof

I have customer http service:

```
    s := &http.Server{
            Addr:         config.Port,
            Handler:      Controller.Log(http.DefaultServeMux),
            ReadTimeout:  3 * time.Second,
            WriteTimeout: 3 * time.Second,
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/exapmle/router/", exampleFunc)

    err := s.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
            log.Critical(err)
            os.Exit(1)
    }
```

It's does't work:

```
go tool pprof http://localhost:8201/debug/pprof/profile
```

return error:

```
Failed to fetch http://localhost:8201/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=30
```

Thanks.

edit:
I think the problem is i rewrite default http server, net/http/pprof package inject http handler:

```
func init() {
    http.Handle("/debug/pprof/", http.HandlerFunc(Index))
    http.Handle("/debug/pprof/cmdline", http.HandlerFunc(Cmdline))
    http.Handle("/debug/pprof/profile", http.HandlerFunc(Profile))
    http.Handle("/debug/pprof/symbol", http.HandlerFunc(Symbol))
}
```

the handler does not work in my code.

Comment: are you importing pprof into the server with: `import _ "net/http/pprof"`?

Comment: Thank you @sir_charles804! Changing the import to that exact string resolved the issue of /debug/pprof 404 errors for me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You set "WriteTimeout" less then profile write time.

on pprof.StartCPUProfile() execute, It already start write, see:

- http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/pprof/pprof.go#L565
- http://golang.org/src/pkg/runtime/pprof/pprof.go#L594

So http.WriteTimeout must be greater than profile write time.

Sorry for my poor English.